# Logging field updates too (while logging row updates)

Tags: mysql, logging, sql-update, comparison

**Goal:**
I am looking for the nice method and idea to log field changes. What is your ideal logging way for the case below?

**Case:**
I need better db update logs for my ecommerce site. I log the product updates just with date. With my existing logs, I have no idea about specific changes on my fields. Ok, the product Deluxe is updated. But which field is changed? Price, color or one of other 20 fields?

I have 2 tables and (for a simple view) I sampled my tables with a few fields

Table1: Product

```
id     name     price   cat     color
1      Deluxe   10      plate   white   
2      Tdog     20      cup     blue
...
```

Table2: Log

```
id     name     date
1      Deluxe   2015-05-05
2      Tdog     2015-05-04
...
```

**MY EXISTING LOGS LOOK LIKE THESE**

```
- Deluxe-1 is updated at 2015-05-05
- Tdog-2 is updated at 2015-05-04
```

**MY LOGS SHOULD BE LIKE BELOW**

```
- Deluxe-1's price is updated (from 10 to 20) at 2015-05-05
- Tdog-2's price is updated (from 20 to 30), color is updated (from blue to green) at 2015-05-04
```